# Property that holds for every $\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I have a question about this logic statement, in $\mathbb{R}$

> If $x$ is such that $x \ge y+ \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon >0$,  then $x \ge y$

That is correct, right? But it calls my attention the "greater than **or** equal". Is this a correct statement?

> If $x$ is such that $x = y+ \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon >0$,  then $x = y$

I think that would be analogous to saying

> If $x$ is such that $x = \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon >0$,  then $x = 0$

but that one last statement looks wrong. Thanks!

Comment: For the second statement, setting $\epsilon = x= y=1$, surely $1 \neq 1 +1 $ ??

Comment: The intuitive reading of $\epsilon$ is : "a small quantity", but this is not what is written by the formula. For every $\epsilon > 0$ means "for every"; thus $x \ge y+ 1.000.000.000$ for example.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks, I just edited that

Comment: But the second statement is TRUE, because $FALSE \to ?$ is TRUE.

Comment: And indeed $x=y+ \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ cannot be satisfied : we cannot have $x=y+1$ and $x=y+2$ and ... This means that in $\mathbb R : \lnot \exists x \forall \epsilon >0 \ (x=y + \epsilon)$.

Comment: There are multiple problems with this. Note that $x$ cannot be equal to two different numbers. Also $x\gt y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ is impossible. If $x\gt y$ consider $\epsilon = x-y+1\gt 0$ to obtain $x\gt x+1$.

Comment: The same for the third one : it is TRUE -in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is right - a false statement implies anything. So whether this question makes sense depends on whether it is essentially a logic question exploring the properties of implication or one which is exploring actual properties of the real numbers.

Comment: @MarkBennet so if I say, let $\varepsilon >0$ arbitrary and after some steps I get in a proof that $x > y + \varepsilon$,  the conclusion that $x \ge y$ is wrong?

Comment: We are not saying that... We have to consider what "arbitrary" means. If $x > y + \epsilon$ for e.g. $\epsilon=1$, clearly : $x > y+1 > y$ and thus the conclusion is $x > y$ and also $x \ge y$. This is sound.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but if I start a proof saying "let $n$ be an arbitrary  natural number" and I conclude for example that $n > -2$, isn't that the same as saying "$n > -2$ for every natural number ? thanks for you patience  :D I just can't see the difference between what I wrote and this famous result for example: "$(\forall \varepsilon > 0) ( 0 \le x < \varepsilon) \Rightarrow x = 0$"

Comment: But **how** you prove that $x > y + \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$ ? This means that $x$ must be "infinite".

Comment: But **how** you prove that $n > -2$ for $n$ "arbitrary" ??? $n=-3$ does not work.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA isn't that why we start with an arbitrary $\varepsilon$?. Now I am very confused with what logicians call generalization

Comment: Your understanding of "generalization" is correct... You use of real numbers is not. When we have in calculus $|x - x_0| < \epsilon$, for every $\epsilon > 0$ we are meaning "every $\epsilon$" and we use this fact in the proof. When you assert $x > \epsilon$ for **every** $\epsilon$, you are meaning that $x$ is infinite, and this means that there is **no** $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $x > \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$.

Comment: @bruceMath That is a different question. The starting point for that investigation is not the size of $\epsilon$ but whether $x\lt y$ is possible or not. If $x\lt y$ then it is small epsilons which will provide the counterexamples. To disprove a statement, you only need one counterexample, you don't need the thing to work for every epsilon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your statements are actually true, because the antecedent in each of them is necessarily false for every $x$ and (where applicable) $y$:

- There **is no** $x$ such that $x\ge y+\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$.
- There **is no** $x$ such that $x= y+\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$.
- There **is no** $x$ such that $x= \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$.

Thus, *no matter what* you conclude from one of these, the implication will be valid.

---

I strongly suspect the statement you wanted to start out with was either

> If $x$ is such that $x \ge y- \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon >0$,  then $x \ge  y$.

or

> If $x$ is such that $x \le y+ \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon >0$,  then $x \le  y$.

which are also true, but for less trivial reasons.

Answer (score 0):

'$x \geq y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$' is diffeernt from '$x > y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ or $x = y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$'. It says that for any particular $\epsilon$ either $x \geq y+\epsilon$ or $x = y+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. That would explain a lot hmm